# Make Bootstrap Carousel move seamlessly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using bootstrap v5 in a project and I want that on clicking the next button, the next slide should start to enter side by side rather than waiting for the first one to leave the viewport(Kind of similar to that carousel implemented by Netflix). Is there any way out to tweak with the default bootstrap code and get the desired result?

The current Carousel HTML:

```
<div id="carousel" className="carousel slide" data-bs-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div className="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F47%2F2020%2F08%2F10%2Fblack-puppy-ball-157684732-2000.jpg&w=412&h=412&c=sc&poi=%5B620%2C519%5D&q=85" alt="dogs" />
      <img src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F47%2F2020%2F08%2F10%2Fblack-puppy-ball-157684732-2000.jpg&w=412&h=412&c=sc&poi=%5B620%2C519%5D&q=85" alt="dogs" />
    </div>
    <div className="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F47%2F2020%2F08%2F10%2Fblack-puppy-ball-157684732-2000.jpg&w=412&h=412&c=sc&poi=%5B620%2C519%5D&q=85" alt="dogs" />
      <img src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F47%2F2020%2F08%2F10%2Fblack-puppy-ball-157684732-2000.jpg&w=412&h=412&c=sc&poi=%5B620%2C519%5D&q=85" alt="dogs" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
</div>
```

Tech Used: Bootstrap v5, Reactjs

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob In VS Code it used to give unwanted warnings so I had to make ```<img>``` a self-closing tag. But I don't think that it will cause any issue.

Comment: Sounds like someone at Microsoft needs to read and understand the HTML specification.